# How to change width of colored progress bar with background linear?

Tags: html, css

I have this css and html code.

My problem is that I see always linear color except color which I defined to 60% as green. From 0 - 60% of width I want to see only green and not others. I thought that when bar is defined as background-image then it will work, but its not.

```css
.bar-line {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 120px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.bar-container {
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 24px;
    max-width: 100%;
    color: #000;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, green 60%, yellow 85%, red 95%);
}
.bar-container:after, .bar-container:before {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.bar-container span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar-line">
    <div class="bar-container" data-percent="30" style="width: 30%;">
        <span>30%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to do it without JS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is more nice to do the html part different

```css
   .bar-line {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #000;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, green 60%, yellow 85%, red 95%);  
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bar-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 24px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.bar-container span {
  text-indent: -100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1000vh;
  right: -1000vh;
  z-index:1; 
}
```

```html
<div class="bar-line">
    <div class="bar-container" data-percent="30" style="width: 30%;">
        <span>30%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just change the width value and see the result :). 
The dirty trick here is to have a very large span, positioned after the bar-container and overlaying the rest of the colored bar-line

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple background and adjust the background-size:

```css
.bar-line {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 120px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.bar-container {
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 24px;
    max-width: 100%;
    color: #000;
    background: 
      linear-gradient(#f1f1f1,#f1f1f1) right/calc(100% - var(--d)) 100% no-repeat,
      linear-gradient(to right, green 60%, yellow 85%, red 95%);
}

.bar-container span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar-line">
    <div class="bar-container" style="--d:30%">
        <span>30%</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bar-line">
    <div class="bar-container" style="--d:50%">
        <span>50%</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bar-line">
    <div class="bar-container" style="--d:80%">
        <span>80%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```